# Translated Picklist Breaks Visualforce Logic When Returning Errors

Tags: apex, visualforce, translation-workbench

I've come across a very strange scenario when using translated picklist values with visualforce.  My scenario is as follows:

- I have a VF page with inputs for a mixture of custom and standard text and picklist fields.
- I've added welsh translations for the picklist fields via the translation workbench.
- In the constructor of the controller I check if a language url parameter has been provided. If it's provided the language parameter in the VF page is set to the paramter value (cy for welsh) or defaulted to English.
- When I load my page with ?lang=cy the page loads correctly in Welsh. The picklist values are displayed in Welsh also.
- If I submit my form without choosing one of the translated picklist values and throw validation errors from my controller the page content is rendered ok.
  (I return a null page reference when returning my errors via apex pagemessages)
- If I choose a value for one of the translated picklist fields and submit (and return for errors not relating to the field I chose the value from), when the page returns the picklist which I chose the value from is displayed in English while picklist inputs which I did not chose a value from are displayed in welsh.

Has anyone come across this before or knows why it may be occurring?

The picklist values should always return or display in welsh or the language provided and not change back to english. it seems strange it only affects the picklist for which I've chosen the value for.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That last bullet point is really hard to read. I suspect it is the most important part of your problem statement as well. Can you try to tidy it up a bit?

Comment: Hi, Thanks. What I meant is that if for example I have two input fields on my page whose values come from translated picklist values.  If I select a value in one of the picklst input fields but do not in the second input field the one I chose a value from displays all of it's values in English when my page reloads (if I return validation errors relating to other fields). The other translated picklist field still displays in welsh. It's all a bit bizarre.

Comment: Is that clearer or still requires further explanation.  Thanks!